# C assigning string to another string results in realloc(): invalid next size

Tags: c, data-structures, memory-management, realloc

I am trying to assign a string in a struct to the string of another struct:

```c
func->parameters[func->parameter_amount].name = tokens[i+1].value;
```

this happens in a while loop:

```c
while (true) {
    func->parameter_amount++;
    func->parameters = realloc(func->parameters, func-> parameter_amount*sizeof(struct parameter));
    if (func->parameters == NULL) {
        mem_error();
    }
    if ((tokens[i].token != symbol) && (tokens[i].token != comma)) {
        break;
    } else if ((tokens[i].token == symbol) && tokens[i+1].token == symbol) {
        func->parameters[func->parameter_amount].type = string_to_type(tokens[i].value);
        if (func->parameters[func->parameter_amount].type == -1) {
            printf("Error: Invalid type '%s' for parameter declaration in function '%s' on line %i\n", tokens[i].value, func->name, func->line);
            exit(1);
        }
        func->parameters[func->parameter_amount].name = tokens[i+1].value;
        i += 2;
    } else if (tokens[i].token == comma) {
        func->parameter_amount--;
        i++;
    }
}
```

after the assignment happens the program says:
`realloc(): invalid next size`
and aborts

the structures are defined as:

```c
struct parameter {
    int type;
    char* name;
};

struct function {
    int line;
    int type;
    char* name;
    struct parameter* parameters;
    int parameter_amount;
};

typedef struct {
    int token;
    char* value;
    int line;
} token;
```

I can't figure out whats going wrong

Comment: Assigning pointers doesn't copy the memory block. If this points to dynamically allocated memory, you need to ensure that you don't free it until you're not using any of the pointers. If you don't do that, you'll dereference a freed pointer, and cause undefined behavior.

Comment: You should probably use `func->parameters[func->parameter_amount].name = strdup(tokens[i+1].value);`

Comment: We really need a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as the root cause may or may not be in the bit of code you have shown. But this looks suspicious: `func->parameters[func->parameter_amount]`. What exact value does `func->parameter_amount` get set to? If it is the number of parameters then the max array index would be `parameter_amount-1`. Using `parameter_amount`would be a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple bugs in your code:

1) After `realloc`, the size of `func->parameters` array is `func->parameterAmount`. So that means that the last index you can use `func->parameterAmount-1`:

```
func->parameters[func->parameterAmount - 1]
```

2) For every element in `func->parameters` array, you have to allocate the string `value` (because at that moment `value` is just a pointer to a character):

```
int i = 0;
int n = 129; // n will be the max length (minus 1) of newly allocated string
for (i = 0; i < func->parameterAmount; ++i) {
    func->parameters[i].name = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * n);
    if (func->parameters[i].name == NULL) {
      // Handle alloc error
    }
}
```

Also, remember to allocate all string variables `value` inside token `array`.

3) In C, you can't assign a value to a string that way. You have to use `strcpy()` from `string.h` header:

```
strcpy(func->parameters[func->parameter_amount].name, tokens[i+1].value);
```